# Rewrite to load homepage for a different url

Tags: pages, templates, url-rewriting, hooks, actions

So I've been wondering if there's a way to force WordPress to load the homepage template for a URL.

Eg.: https://example.com/example/another-example/my-post-slug/ should load the template belonging to https://example.com but some widgets would display different data according to the slug in the URI.

Maybe there's an action or a hook that could do this? This would be trivial to solve within an MVC framework, not so much in WP.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [custom template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates) and assign that to both your homepage as well as that specific post. Templates are normally for the `page` post type, but you can add

`* Template Post Type: post, page`

to the comment at the top of the template file to make this available for posts as well.

You can then use Wordpress functions such as [is_front_page()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) to check to see if you are on your homepage or just a post page - this would allow you to load different widget areas / sidebars.